# MongoDB query with only one field of a compound index

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

Let's say I have a compound index that uses the following two fields in order: GroupId, NameId. Then at some point I want to query the collection, but I only have access to the NameId, then how does MongoDB do this search, if the first field(s) of a compound index aren't used for the query? Is linear search used for each Group, but then it utilizes the NameId since the NameIds are sorted within each group? Or does it ignore the NameId field too and only use linear search?

In short, can field A of the compound index "sabotage" and force linear search for fields B and/or C if not A is used? Or is binary search still used for the B and C fields?

Comment: You can test what mongodb is doing with [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

Comment: [Index prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) might be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I will read about prefixes and test explain().

Comment: According to index prefixes it seems like you have to incluse the first index, you can't just use fields B and C of compound index with fields A, B and C for example.